# Using pulling information from a python function to a template

Tags: python, django-models, django-templates

I have Event objects being shown properly. But I can't seem to grab the result from a python function and place it into the template.

For instance, this is my Event model.

```
class Event(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    students = models.ManyToManyField(StudentProfile, null=True, blank=True)
    managers = models.ManyToManyField(ManagerProfile, null=True, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    def attendees(self):
        return len(self.students.count + self.managers.count)
```

I can successfully pull everything into my template except attendees... For instance within a search context, I'm passing events as results...

`{{ result.name }}` is passed into my template fine, so is `{{ result.location }}`.

But `{{ result.attendees|length }}` won't show.

Any idea why this is? Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `{{ result.attendees }}` (no `|length`).

The `length` filter works on lists and other iterables. What you're doing there is similar to applying `len(len(something))`, which is obviously wrong.

Comment: It seems that `{{ result.attendees }}` doesn't show either. :/